# resource identifier xxxxxxxx has already been used in this assembly

Tags: .net, workflow, c#-3.0, workflow-foundation, csc

Compiling a Workflow with ***Visual Studio 2010*** and ***.Net Framework 3.0*** results in this ***CSC*** error:

**"resource identifier xxxxxxxx has already been used in this assembly"**

where xxxxxxxx is a Workflow Type in my Project.

I'm using Workflow Foundation 3.
Thanks for your help,
Tom

Comment: I have this problem with Xamarin.iOs, I deleted the duplicated resource and still getting this exception.

Comment: Well I never actually solved the problem.. the day after everything was working fine again. Maybe could be a sort of hiccup with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 5):

There is likely a folder in your project with some controls that should not be compiled again.

The simplest solution would be to Right-Click the folder with xxxxxxxx in it, and select "Exclude from Project"

DO NOT DELETE THE FOLDER!

[image: sample pic]

Comment: We get this kind of problem quite rarely and only on several production machines, it's very hard to reproduce. I'll try your suggestion once it occurs again.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Was getting this same issue recently in VS IDE - traced this down to the **CSPROJ** having the same import twice for a nuget package. If you see this - comb through your **CSPROJ** looking for duplicate `<Import/>` elements for the same asset.