# Migrating to .NET MAUI from Xamarin forms keeps getting "Resource identifier has already been used in this assembly"

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-maui

I have painfully migrated and replaced namespaces , references and everything else to use .NET maui. However I'm down to 15 errors and all they say is "Resource identifier xxxx has already been used in this assembly" where xxx is a xaml page.

I have provided the error screenshot below and a sample xaml page that is being rendered as "erroneous". I've checked the csproj file but nothing seems out of the ordinary. (also attached below as code snippet)

How do get rid of this error?

[image: error screenshot]

[image: sample xaml]

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-ios;net6.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseMaui>True</UseMaui>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;NETSTANDARD;NETSTANDARD2_0;__IOS__</DefineConstants>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Models\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Models\**" />
      <None Remove="Models\**" />
    <None Remove="Assets\styles.css" />
    <None Remove="Views\ContentViews\ProductList\" />
    <None Remove="Views\Templates\ProductList\" />
    <None Remove="System.Drawing.Common" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies" Version="6.0.541" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Extensions" Version="6.0.541" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.DryIoc.Maui" Version="8.1.273-pre" />
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Maui" Version="8.1.273-pre" />
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Maui.Rx" Version="8.1.273-pre" />
    <PackageReference Include="PropertyChanged.Fody" Version="3.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="CarouselView.FormsPlugin" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers" Version="0.4.346202">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Assets\styles.css" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\AboutPage.xaml" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\ItemDetailPage.xaml" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\ItemsPage.xaml" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\MainPage.xaml" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\MenuPage.xaml" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\NewItemPage.xaml" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\SuddnBottomNav.xaml" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\SuddnDashboard.xaml" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\SuddnMap.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Controls\ExtendedEditorControl.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Controls\ExtendedListView.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Helpers\ChatTemplateSelector.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="ViewModels\ChatPageViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="ViewModels\DineStackViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="ViewModels\SuddnBottomNavViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="ViewModels\SuddnDashboardViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\AboutPage.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\Cells\IncomingViewCell.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\Cells\OutgoingViewCell.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\ChatPage.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\DineStack.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\ItemDetailPage.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\ItemsPage.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\MainPage.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\MenuPage.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\NewItemPage.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="CachingImageFactory.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\Results\Candidates.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\Results\Address_Components.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\Results\Geometry.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\Partials\ChatInputBarView.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\SuddnBottomNav.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\SuddnDashboard.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Views\SuddnMap.xaml.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="resource\iconmonstr-gear-11-240.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Views\Cells\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Partials\" />
    <Folder Include="Controls\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\ContentViews\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\ContentViews\ProfilePage\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Templates\" />
    <Folder Include="ViewModelAccessors\" />
    <Folder Include="Converters\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Product\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\ContentViews\ProductList\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Templates\ProductList\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\SariModels\SariModels.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MauiXaml Remove="Views\Cells\IncomingViewCell.xaml" />
    <MauiXaml Remove="Views\Cells\OutgoingViewCell.xaml" />
    <MauiXaml Remove="Views\ChatPage.xaml" />
    <MauiXaml Remove="Views\DineStack.xaml" />
    <MauiXaml Remove="Views\Partials\ChatInputBarView.xaml" />
    <MauiXaml Remove="Views\SuddnBottomNav.xaml" />
    <MauiXaml Remove="Views\SuddnDashboard.xaml" />
    <MauiXaml Remove="Views\SuddnMap.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\ProfilePage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\SignupPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-android'">
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154639/resource-identifier-xxxxxxxx-has-already-been-used-in-this-assembly). By the way, did you forget to add `x:Class="xxx"` on the xaml page screenshot you provided?

Comment: hi, I have already checked that but to no avail. I guess I'll end up "remaking" my xamarin project using a new solution targeting MAUI. My project only still has a few features implemented and in my situation its a lot more headache to migrate the existing one.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Are all the errors "Resource identifier xxxx`.xaml` has already been used in this assembly"? If so, you can check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/22a73841-cadb-4570-b86a-6cfc8128481f/resource-identifier-has-already-been-used-in-this-assembly?forum=xamarinforms). Hope it can help you.